# Live templates in PhpStorm not useful

Tags: phpstorm

I installed "Live Templates for Angular" plugin in PhpStorm. I think something is wrong with suggestion (triggered with <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>). I have to write whole snippet `a-component` to get to right suggestion.

Can I improve it somehow in settings?

Here is a gif:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the template name (abbreviation) has a dash `-` in it ... and when completing IDE treats `a` and `component` as separate parts until whole match is found (in case you were doing some subtraction operation with two variables). At very least that's my understanding of this behaviour based on my own usage experience.

You may just change the abbreviation and remove `-` from there and it will be much better recognized as valid completion item. But that may not be ideal in long run (potentially may have issues when plugin will be updated with new templates etc.)

To bypass it ... just use *Live Template specific completion* where only Live Templates will be listed. For that invoke shortcut assigned to `Code | Insert Live Template...` action (<kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd> on Windows using Default keymap) at any time when you're typing your Live Template abbreviation.

Comment: It must be the case. Great shortcut for `insert live template`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the **applicable context yet**.

Apply to the specified type of file, or check everywhere.

Like below:

[image]